# how to have my email script run only when a 'host is offline' not when the result comes back as 'host online'

Tags: python-3.x

I have tried a couple of different ways to execute the file. every time I run the code I get email whether the ping is successful or not. I only want an email when the ping is successful.  This is for me and my team to know if a computer goes offline or not.

```
from subprocess import PIPE, Popen
import Email

num = 1
host = "192.168.1.116"
wait = 1000

ping = Popen("ping -n {} -w {} {}".format(num, wait, host),
         stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE)
exit_code = ping.wait()

if exit_code != 0:
    print("Host offline.")
    exec(Email)
else:
    print("Host online.")
```

Comment: sorry in the question I want an email when the ping is not successful.

Comment: What are you getting as a value in `exit_code`?

Comment: What is `exec(Email)` supposed to do and what does the Email module contain?

Comment: when I stop the loop i get and exit code-1

Comment: the exec(Email) calls the email code that is on a separate file. when it calls the code sends a text email to 2 adresses telling me that the server is down

Answer (score 0):

The exec(email)  calls the email code thats is in a different section of code, to send an email with text that says the ping failed and the server is down.